# How do I use hex in an audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, hex

i'm wondering how i would go about inserting hex into a page as audio and it be usable, something like:

```html
<audio>
  *hex here*
</audio>
```

sorry if im not to clear on what im communicating but could somebody help me if you know what i'm saying but i want to have audio in my page without an external file embedded